# How to disable a cell in a DataGrid while binding to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

In my program I have a UserControl that contains a `DataGrid` that has it's `ItemsSource` bound to an `ObservableCollection`. For that `DataGrid` I need to be able to disable and gray out specific cells. I would like to do this preferably in c++, because I might need to change which cells this happens to at run time. I know how to use `IsReadOnly`, but it appears that I can only toggle that for an entire column. This becomes a problem because my columns are bound to data, which makes it harder for me to target specific grid cells.

With that being said,

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Collection}" ... >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
          <!-- Row Number -->
          <DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding rowNum}" />
          <!-- Inputs -->
          <DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="False" Header="Inputs" Binding="{Binding input}" />
          <!-- Outputs -->
          <DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="False" Header="Outputs" Binding="{Binding output}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Data Model:

```
namespace Program.Data_Models
{
    public class CartIO_Model : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private string test1 = "One";
        private string test2 = "Two";
        private string test3 = "Three";
        private string DISABLEDtest4 = "Four";
        private string DISABLEDtest5 = "Five";

        private ObservableCollection<collectionData> _collection; 

        public CartIO_Model()
        {
            Collection = new ObservableCollection<collectionData>();
            Collection.Add(new collectionData() { rowNum = 0, input = test1, output = ""});
            Collection.Add(new collectionData() { rowNum = 1, input = test2, output = ""});
            Collection.Add(new collectionData() { rowNum = 2, input = "", output = test3 });
            Collection.Add(new collectionData() { rowNum = 3, input = "", output = DISABLEDtest4 });
            Collection.Add(new collectionData() { rowNum = 4, input = DISABLEDtest5, output = ""});

        }

        public ObservableCollection<collectionData> Collection
        {...}
    }

    public class collectionData
    {
        public int rowNum { set; get; }
        public string input { set; get; }
        public string output { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Where and how would I control which cells are enabled/disabled? This confuses me because `IsEnabled` is a trait of a View control, not that of an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: on what condition you want your cells to be disabled..is in the value of some property in collectionData class?

Comment: It actually depends which radio button is selected in a different ViewModel->Model. Is that where I would perform these operations on the `DataGrid`?

Comment: sorry but i dont understand, so on selection of radio button you want to disable some cells in datagrid.. but how are you deciding which cell would those be.. wont which cell to disable depend on the data inside them?

Comment: Yes on the first part. About deciding which cells those would be.. programmatically that's what I'm having trouble with. The cell to disable depends on it's location. For example: If you select `RadioButton1`, maybe the third cell in row12 gets disabled. I hope that is a little clearer...

Comment: i would suggest you to keep it data-driven, update/create property on model which will decide if cell will be enabled or not.. you can refer to my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define `CellStyle` for your Column and enable/disable the cells depending on any data in model or viewmodel. Here i have disabled all the cells in Inputs column which has input value as Test4

```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Collection}"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!-- Row Number -->
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToCells"  Binding="{Binding rowNum}">

            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <!-- Inputs -->
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToCells" Header="Inputs" Binding="{Binding input}" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding input}" Value="Four">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <!-- Outputs -->
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="False" Header="Outputs" Binding="{Binding output}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you only do this for a whole column, or can I target specific cells (How would I since the cells are determined at run-time?) ?

Comment: this will disable only those cell in column which has specific value.. offcourse if you bind to some property on ViewModel,it can disable the whole column also

Comment: Oh, I see. With this strategy, how would I ever be able to control the `IsEnabled` state based on the location of the cell. For example: no matter what is in row 4, column 2, when I select a `RadioButton` in the other part of my program, that cell gets disabled.

Comment: thats what i am suggesting above also, dont go by location, define the property on your model and set its value to decide whether the cell should be enabled or not. Then bind those cells which you want to toggle enable state to that property in cellstyle like in answer.. whatever cell's model will have that property it will be disabled..

Comment: sorry buddy, could not join the chat.. did you get it to work?

Comment: I got it to work, I was just going to ask how to change which cells are disabled at run-time

Comment: That's probably a separate question though.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a style of TextBox.

```
    <Style x:Key="PoBodyTextBoxEditableStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource PoStatusToEditableConverter}}"
                         Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                        Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

and set the EditingElementStyle.

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MyTextColumn"
                    Binding="{Binding MyText}"
                    Header="MyHeader"
                    Width="Auto"
                    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MyTextBoxEditableStyle}" />
```