# Disable specific DataGridCheckBoxColumn cells via ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

My MVVM project has this ViewModel:

```
class ListViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public ObservableCollection<ListItemviewModel> Items { ... }
}
class ListItemViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public String  Name      { ... }
    public Boolean IsChecked { ... }
    public Boolean IsEnabled { ... }
}
```

Writing the XAML seemed straightforward:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn     Header="Name"       Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is checked" Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" />
</DataGrid>
```

However, how can I get it so when a `ListItemViewModel`'s `IsEnabled` property is `false` the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`'s cell in that row is disabled?

I tried setting `IsReadOnly={Binding IsDisabled}` (and adding an `IsDisabled` property to `ListItemViewModel`, however to no avail) - and I recognise that would disable/enable the whole column, not individual cells.

I also tried these instructions ( [How to disable a cell in a DataGrid while binding to an ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572984/how-to-disable-a-cell-in-a-datagrid-while-binding-to-an-observablecollection) ):

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is checked" Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" />
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
```

However this has no effect and no binding errors are displayed in the Output window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out the question I linked to ( [How to disable a cell in a DataGrid while binding to an ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572984/how-to-disable-a-cell-in-a-datagrid-while-binding-to-an-observablecollection) ) was almost-right, but the XAML was somewhat cargo-cultish. The correct XAML is merely:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
    </Style>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
```

Sorted!